# No route found for "POST /user": Method Not Allowed (Allow: GET)

Tags: php, symfony-3.4

i try add routes:

- POST /user - create user
- GET /user - get list of users

my *app/config/routing.yml*:

```
app:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Resources/route/app.yml"
    prefix:   /
```

*AppBundle/Resources/route/app.yml*:

```
user:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Resources/route/user.yml"
    prefix:   /user
```

*AppBundle/Resources/route/user.yml*:

```
list:
    path:     /
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:User:list }
    methods:  GET

create:
    path:     /
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:User:create }
    methods:  POST
```

i have installed **friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle** (UserController extends FOSRestController)

app/config/security.yml:

```
security:

    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory: ~

    firewalls:

        api:
            pattern:   ^/
            stateless: true
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator
```

when i make a request for a route POST /user, i get an error

```
No route found for "POST /user": Method Not Allowed (Allow: GET)
```

Comment: I don't think that you can use the same route for two different actions

Comment: i saw [here](http://symfony.com/doc/2.6/cookbook/routing/method_parameters.html), but i use 3.4 version symfony framework. It does not work anymore?

Comment: [found for my version](http://symfony.com/doc/3.4/routing/requirements.html#adding-http-method-requirements)

Comment: Oh, cool, didn't know about that. But following the documentation, it could help to place the allowed methods in brackets

Comment: I wrote in brackets and without - the result does not change :(

Comment: I noticed that the problem disappears if you move the routes from user.yml to app.yml...
why is this happening?